# how to add Click event for a button inside a Bootstrap modal 4.0

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have a simple Modal (Bootstrap 4).
I wand to add some `click` functionality to `save` and `cacel` buttons .

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="cancel"  class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how should I implement it? as far as I read in documentation ([Bootstrap’s JavaScript modal plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#options)), there exist no button option.
I also tried :

```
$(document).on( "click", "#submit", function() {
       alert("submit click");
    });
```

but the function call by any click and anywher (input, modal, ...).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to add event to the buttons in this model (not from other locations), just use the id selector instead of document.

```js
$("#exampleModal").on( "click", "#submit", function() {
   alert("submit click");
});
$("#exampleModal").on( "click", "#cancel", function() {
   alert("cancel click");
});
```